# Reference request: Kummer étale topology and tame topology

Tags: reference-request, etale-covers, log-geometry

In Theorem 7.6 of [Illusie - An overview of the work of K. Fujiwara, K. Kato, and C. Nakayama on logarithmic étale cohomology](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_2002__279__271_0) it is stated that if $X$ is a log regular fs log scheme and $U$ is the open subschema where the log structure is trivial, then the Kummer-étale site of $X$ is equivalent to the curve-tame site of $U$. The proof is not written there, and it cites a mysterious paper of Fujiwara and Kato that apparently was never published (or at least I have not been able to find it). This result seems to be well known and (as far as I understand) not trivial at all, but I cannot find a reference where this is proved.

Answer (score 3):

He did not say that the sites are equal as this claim is wrong in general, but that the categories of covers, i.e. **finite** morphisms which cover the log scheme (See definition 3.1. of the same paper), are equivalent. There is a written proof in theorem 13.3.45 of [Almost purity and perfectoid spaces by Gabber and Romero](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/%7Eramero/hodge.pdf).

Comment: I am having trouble inferring the end of the sentence: "but the category of covers …".

Comment: You are right. I finished the sentence.